# Resharper naming conventions stumble over underscore?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper-6.0

I've set Resharper to start everything with in lowercase.

Now, when Visual Studio generates event methodes, like `searchButton_Click` it warns me that this is not conforming to my naming conventions.

This seems to be because of the underscore in the middle of the sentense. The only other settings with underscores in it are all_lower and ALL_UPPER. But I want just the start of the method or variable to be lowerscore and the rest to use camelCasing.

Is there no setting for this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you don't use that naming convention.  Most people will view it as inconsistent.  I also recommend that you don't use the default method names.  For example, I would have the click method for `searchButton` simply called `Search`, or something else appropriate like `StartSearch`

Comment: I don't see how this can be inconsistent. It's just different, that doesn't mean it isn't consistent in it's own right.

Comment: I didn't say it was inconsistent.  If all your event methods are like that, it would be consistent.  However, most people will perceive it as inconsistent nonetheless.